# CSS background-image code does not show up image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I am trying to build a small website using HTML, bootstrap and css (I am a newbie). However in the css background-image does not work. I have checked the path and the file format and it is fine (infact am using brackets ide and it shows a thumbnail of the image when I hover the mouse over the path). Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My First Web Project</title>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- NAVIGATION HEADER -->

  <div class="header" id="topheader">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container text-uppercase p-2"> 
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MY WEBSITE</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
      <!-- BODY SECTION -->
   <section class="header-section">
       <div class="center-div">
           <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
           <p>Hello we are developing this site</p>
       </div>

       <div class="header-buttons">
           <a href="#">EXPLORE</a>
           <a href="#">CONTACT</a>

       </div>

   </section> 
</div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{padding:0; margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.header
{

    background: url('../images/background.jpg');

}
```

Please help!

Comment: Where is Your css file located and where is your image located ? with '../' you're referring the parent folder of the css file location.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro My folder hierarchy:

HTML Projects>css, images, index.htm

Comment: @Rob I understand its a simple issue, but I have tried all. Would you be kind enough to point out what the issue is? PS: I have tried deleting the browser cache as well.

Comment: You're referring href="styles.css" in your code. so the styles.css is located in the same folder where index.htm is located ? I think it should be /css/styles.css or ./css/styles.css

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro I also tried adding an image from the web with the exact path (https://...........) it did not work!

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css"> or <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css"> if styles.css is in css folder. Also You use bootstrap try to rename class="header" to something different. header name for a class may have been used by bootstrap or put !important after the image url background: background: url('../images/background.jpg') !important;

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your browser DevTools (right click on page and hit Inspect or CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome) to see if there is anything overriding your CSS?

It could also be the URL needs to change.. try changing it to the following:

```
background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
```

If you've tried to put in a URL directly from the web as mentioned and it still didn't work, then I suggest checking out if something is overriding the code, maybe declare !important in your CSS line to see if that makes a difference.

I've also experienced a few cases where the image was a JPEG and had to change it from JPG in the CSS. Check your browser Dev Tools to see what's going on. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS code to this and try it out:

```
.header
{
    background: url('images/background.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give width and height to div that has a background image with background-size: cover

```
    .header
    {
        background: url('images/background.jpg');
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    background-size:contain
    }
```

Comment: the header div contains bootstrap elements which already defines their width and height so the parent div will take the dimensions of their children. This is not needed